# How to Read Directory Without Recursion in Java

Tags: java, file, object, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to use my own object to process directories and files. I need to print the directory name and its contents along with the contents of its subdirectories until the stack is empty. For some reason I get a null pointer exception. Here is my code. The commented out code is when the code works but with File objects not my own. I need to use my own object for this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DirInfo {
    
    String parentName = "";
    String childName = "";
    String fileName = "";
    
    public void readDirectory() throws IOException {
        DirInfo file = new DirInfo();
        ArrayBoundedStack<DirInfo> stack = new ArrayBoundedStack<DirInfo>();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a directory to read.");
        //String dir = kb.next();
        parentName = kb.next();
        kb.close();
        
        stack.push(file);
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            File currentDir = new File(parentName);
            DirInfo current = stack.top();
            //String parentName = current.getName();
            System.out.println(parentName);
            stack.pop();
            
            
            File [] files = currentDir.listFiles();
            
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    //stack.push(new File(current, f.getName()));
                    parentName = f.getName();
                    stack.push(new DirInfo());
                    //System.out.println("\t" + f.getName());
                    System.out.println("\t" + parentName);
                }
                else {
                    fileName = f.getName();
                    //System.out.println("\t" + f.getName());
                    System.out.println("\t" + fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main File:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class DirectoryRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DirInfo scan = new DirInfo();
        scan.readDirectory();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a directory to read.
C:\\DirFolder1
C:\\DirFolder1
    DirFolder2
    Sample File1.txt
DirFolder2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DirInfo.readDirectory(DirInfo.java:32)
    at DirectoryRead.main(DirectoryRead.java:7)
```

Comment: Which line is line 32?

Comment: @Is this a school assignment? Is that why you want to do this without recursion?

Comment: Line 32 has the for loop for reading the files in the `files` array. @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new DirInfo here

```
              stack.push(new DirInfo());
```

then you are trying to read from it later

```
              File [] files = currentDir.listFiles();
```

Comment: it is quite possible